# Removing Empty values from ArrayList

Tags: vba, arraylist

So I have an ArrayList that has a Empty value. It is not a blank or a "". It is just Empty. How do I remove it from the ArrayList

I tried list1.Remove("") but obviously it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work?

```
Dim newArrList As New ArrayList
Dim el As Variant

For Each el in myArrayList
    If IsEmpty(el) Then newArrList.Add el
Next el
```

Comment: @RitamChakrabarty well what is not working - where does it break/where does it differ from the expected output? We are not mind readers, if you want help with your problems you at least have to tell us what isn't working / how it differs from what you want. Because "it isn't working" isn't helpful (this also applies to your question)

Comment: It is working. Thanks @Lord-JulianXLII. I made a mistake while writing it.